# objective-c Embedded UICollectionViewController shows 0 items

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to have a UICollectionViewController inside my UIViewController. 
Here's how I set it up

```
TagsCollectionViewController* tagsCollectionViewController = [[TagsCollectionViewController alloc] initWithCollectionViewLayout:[UICollectionViewLayout new]];
    UIView *tagsView = tagsCollectionViewController.view;
    [self.view addSubview:tagsView]; // setting up constraings too
```

And this is my `TagsCollectionViewController`

```
@interface TagsCollectionViewController () <UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>

@end

@implementation TagsCollectionViewController

static NSString * const reuseIdentifier = @"Cell";

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

}

#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDataSource>

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 20;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    return cell;

}

#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return  CGSizeMake(50, 50);
}

@end
```

What's strange is that I get yellow view so my collection seems to be working, however I don't get to see any items. But when I present whole controller everything works fine. So the problem occurs only when I'm trying to embed it. What can be the issue?

EDIT: Related: [Adding UICollectionViewController to UIViewController Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891660/adding-uicollectionviewcontroller-to-uiviewcontroller-not-working?rq=1)

Comment: Do you keep a valid reference to your `TagsCollectionViewController` around so it can act as the delegate/datasource?

Comment: @PhillipMills I made it a strong property now and initialized it in viewDidLoad. Is that what you meant? Still doesn't work though.

Comment: Does its methods get called, e.g. for number of items?  (Maybe put in a breakpoint to see what you're returning.)

Comment: Yes, it gets called and it works just fine as a separate controller. It probably has to do something with the way I embed it.

Comment: That's OK but I suspect `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is not being called at all.

Comment: @PhillipMills yeah I don't know why I said that, I honestly tried to making it a property and it didn't work, but that seemed to be the issue. Making it a property and then using it solved it.

Comment: @PhillipMills I was initializing it with UICollectionViewLayout instead of UICollectionViewFlowLayout...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if it's a problem with estimating the size of items in the collection.  I was able to get results by using the following code after creating a similar example and noticing that cells weren't being requested.

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) TagsCollectionViewController *tags;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [UICollectionViewFlowLayout new];
    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(50.0, 50.0);
    self.tags = [[TagsCollectionViewController alloc] initWithCollectionViewLayout:layout];
    UIView *tagsView = self.tags.view;
    [self.view addSubview:tagsView];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
I honestly not quite sure how, but it worked!!

Comment: Not sure either.  Perhaps when you present the controller directly it applies some default sizing and, without that, decides not to ask for cells because it doesn't know how to display them.  (Just guessing.)

Comment: It actually works even without itemSize, I'm almost sure that I tried the exact version but it didn't work back then, huh

Comment: I was initializing it with UICollectionViewLayout instead of UICollectionViewFlowLayout...

Comment: Yes, I think I gave you the right answer but with the wrong reasoning.  :)